# Chinese stroke order diagram styles resources

Tags: resources, stroke-order, orthography

I'm looking for a resource online that shows the stroke orders of a character in just one box for my Anki flashcards on my phone. The format should look something like [this](https://kanji.nihongo.cz/jiscode/13115/l/en) (unfortunately it's Kanji only which doesn't have characters like 员) or even better [colored](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObesD.png) (from Fluent Forever's model decks)

But the resources I've found so far use [animations](https://www.yellowbridge.com/chinese/character-stroke-order.php?word=%E5%9B%BD) (which might not even play on my phone, it'll also take quite a while to finish if it does especially for complex Hanzi) or the [grid format](https://www.archchinese.com/chinese_stroke_sequence_image_generator.html) which doesn't sit well with the aspect ratio of phones (the steps will look small to the eyes)

Does anyone know some Chinese resources with the stroke order diagrams I want?

Answer (score 1):

This site is quite good. It doesn't contain any ancient Flash or Java components, and displays the character in complete stroke order in one single static image, or animation if you prefer.

https://strokeorder.com.tw/

[image]

Although the interface is in Chinese, it's easy to understand, you put a character in the text field and click the magnifying glass button to search.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using a code made by ThoreBor (check out his anki addons for Chinese learning, they're really useful) that inputs stroke order animations onto my stroke order cards https://github.com/ThoreBor/Hanzi-Writer-for-Anki/blob/master/anki_hanzi_writer_without_dropdown.html It uses the animations from hanziwriter.org . I'm also using the Fluent Forever model deck for Chinese, nice to see there are others doing too. Feel free to contact me if you need any assistance, I've been really building upon it on my own. The animations works fine on AnkiDroid from what I've tested.